# Database Project: How to update while maintaining data

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2012

I have a database project in my Visual Studio project. As I am in iteration 1 development, whenever I make changes to the database project and push the changes, I've been dropping all the test data b/c the "Compare Schema" => "Update Target" function fails if I have data in the table with changes b/c `N'Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur.` At this time it's fine, but once I push to production, I will have database changes and data that needs to be maintained.

My question is this: How do I use the database project to update my production database with "update" & "alter" statements so that no data is lost?

If this is not possible, what's the alternative? It seems very silly to have a tool that is built to maintain databases but can't handle production systems and maintain the data.

Comment: It's not *silly* at all. Updating databases while maintaining existing data is not a simple feat, and many different factors play into how you go about it. When writing your scripts to update the database, you will just have to be careful when creating them to avoid writing anything that will result in a loss of data (unless you purposely want to drop some data). It's not an easy subject. Nick Craver (Stack Overflow developer) has a handy [blog post](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/05/03/stack-overflow-how-we-do-deployment-2016-edition/) about how they handle migrations that may be helpful.

Comment: So I have to manually write the scripts? There isn't a way to generate the scripts?

Comment: That's what we do at our company. We have a database project that is used to generate a "create script" for a new database, but we use tools like Red Gate SQL Compare to generate "migration scripts" that we can apply to existing databases to bring their schema up to alignment. Those migration scripts get checked into source code control. And for syncing those changes, we have a custom tool that's similar to [DbUp](https://dbup.github.io/). We've got literally 5,000 databases and so far, so good.

Comment: if your changes destroy or alter data in a way that can't be reconciled, or would result in loss, then of course it will complain. If the change is necessary, then you need to do additional work to preserve or transform the data, or maybe you decide that the data is no longer required. That's just a simple fact of DB maintenance. If you make a change the won't result in loss (e.g. just add a new column or table) then probably you'd have no issues. The tool is, rightly, warning you that you're going to do damage, and you need to take action. It can't decide for you what the action should be.

Comment: I'll look into a migration tool - thanks.